# Do I need to unsubscribe from dynamic menu item events?

Tags: c#, events, menu

I am dynamically creating a context menu with many nested menu items.  I clear out the menu and recreate the menu items each time the context menu is shown.  Do I need to unsubscribe from these menuitem click events?  I am thinking that when I clear the ContextMenu.Items list, the menu items are picked up by the garbage collector and I do not need to worry about them.

```
void Window_ContextMenuOpening(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.ContextMenu == null)
           ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        else
           ContextMenu.Items.Clear();

        AddMenuItemsToContextMenu();
    }

void AddMenuItemsToContextMenu()
{
    //create many nested menu items
    foreach (A in AList)
    {
        MenuItem item = new MenuItem();
        item.Header = A.Label;
        item.Click += MenuItem_Click;
        ContextMenu.Items.Add(item);

        //possibly add more menu items to this menu item
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `item.Click += MenuItem_Click;` it is the `MenuItem` that holds a reference to your `Form` so once you remove the last reference to the control in `ContextMenu.Items.Clear();` the garbage collector will eventually collect the items that where in the collection which will also collect the events that where created therein.

The thing that can get you in a sticky situation is when the class publishing the event is a static object or a unexpected additional reference to the publishing object is held somewhere else then that chain of references (`additional reference -> object publishing event -> object subscribing to event`) can keep that last subscribing object alive longer than expected.